# How do I convert one element (or key) of an array into a string variable?

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
array
(
[0] => "string0"
[1] => "string1"
)
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
$str = array[0];
print_r ($str);
```

And get a result like this:

```
"string0"
```

Instead I am getting this:

```
str
(
[0] => "string0"
)
```

I want to take one element of an array and turn it into a string.

Comment: Then don't use `print_r` if you don't like its output. Use `print` or `var_export`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `echo` or `print` instead of `print_r`

```
$str = $array[0];
echo $str;
```

`print_r` is used to show information about the variable
`echo` + `print` are used to directly output the variable

Comment: When I do that I get `Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/demo.php on line 134`

Comment: then $array[0] is an array and not a string - i assume you are looking at a multidimensional array

Comment: Aha! Yes! So how can I get the string out of the array in the array? :-)

Comment: just use echo then the array variable then the array element key
`echo $array[0];` and make sure you have the dollar sign before `array[0];`

Comment: without seeing the array - how could any one possibly answer, please read the tarry section of the manual.

Comment: Here is how I accomplished what I needed to do: `array[$key][$k] = array[$key][$k][0];`